# How to calculate the actuarial reserve with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, math

i want to calculate the actuarial reserve with pandas over some years, with an Excel as Input:
[image]

The thing i want to receive is the red column, the actuarial reserve.
You calculate it for the first year with 1000*1,007 = 1007/ for the second year with (1007+1500)*1,007 and so on.

The problem i have with pandas is that i have to use the calcuated DK from the last year (for example 1007) in the next step.

Here is my try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('DK_pandas.xlsx')

df['DK2']=np.nan

x = df.loc[0]['Start']
z = df.loc[0]['Start']*df.loc[0]['1+zins']
y = len(df)


start = df.loc[0]['Start']*df.loc[0]['1+zins']
df['DK2'] = start

for i in range(1,y,1): # gehe über die Indizes
    print(i)
    dk_weiter = (df.loc[i]['Start']+df.loc[i-1]['DK2'])*df.loc[i]['1+zins']
    print(dk_weiter)

print(df.head(10))

Start  1+zins  aufzinsen      DK
0   1000    1.01       1.01 1007.00
1   1500    1.01       1.01 2524.55
2   -200    1.01       1.02 2340.82
```

There are only 3 rows for this example!
for the first two years everything is fine, but then it fails :(
Can someone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To get better suggestions: Please don't post pictures (edit and replace with a df.head(10) output).  Also to be clear on the calculation you should post the spreadsheet formulae that you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get 234082084 in my spreadsheet; I get 2542019443 which matches the code below.

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

'''Given:

   Start  1+zins  aufzinsen
0   1000    1007       1007
1   1500    1007    1014049
2   -200    1007  102114734
'''

df = pd.read_excel('DK_pandas.xlsx')

# set starting value of 'DK2'
df.loc[0, 'DK2'] = df.loc[0, '1+zins']

print(df, '\n\n')

''' Shows:

   Start  1+zins  aufzinsen      DK2
0   1000    1007       1007 1007.000
1   1500    1007    1014049      NaN
2   -200    1007  102114734      NaN 
'''

# remove scientific notation
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

for i in range(1, len(df)):    
    df.loc[i, 'DK2'] = (df.loc[i,'Start'] + df.loc[i-1,'DK2']) * df.loc[i, '1+zins']


print(df)

''' Shows (FYI: '2542019443' doesn't match '234082084' 
shown in screenshot in the question):

   Start  1+zins  aufzinsen            DK2
0   1000    1007       1007       1007.000
1   1500    1007    1014049    2524549.000
2   -200    1007  102114734 2542019443.000
'''

print('\n')
```

Comment: that helped (i got my results and not this 2542019443 at the end, but i can't find the difference...doesn't matter :) ) thanks  a lot!